# Using calculus to determine how many roots are real

Tags: calculus, roots

For the first one the calculus makes sense $f= x^3-3x+1$. So consider $f' = 3x^2 -3$ which has zeros at $\pm 1$. Then $f(1) = -3$ is negative and $f(-1) = 1$ is positive. S we know it actually crosses the x-axis between $(-1,1)$. I'm not sure how we get from that there are 3 real roots?

Then for second one, $g= x^3-3x+7$, so obviously same derivative and zeros. Here though $g(1) = 5$ and $g(-1) = 9$ and I'm not sure where to go from there because the intersection actually happens between $(-3, -2)$ and that gives that we only have one real root which I also don't understand

Comment: The fact that $f(-1) > 0$ also indicates that $f$ has a root in $(-\infty,1)$. (Why?) Similarly, the fact $f(1) < 0$ indicates that $f$ has a root in $(1,\infty)$. (Why?)

Comment: I simply meant that I needed to evaluate at $\pm 1$ again but I don't know how to interpret the outcome of that substitution

Comment: @AntonioVargas I have an intuitive idea that the it has to do with the signs  having to change again. Like it's decreasing at 1 so intersects x-axis and so has to cross again. Is that on the right track?

Comment: It is not decreasing at $1$ though, because $f'(1) = 0$. However, you're right that the sign needs to change again, so take a little bit to think about why that must be so for this particular function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Consider graphing  $ y = x^3-3 x + A $ for some values of A. The chosen value of A has the effect of raising or lowering entire graph along y-direction.

Find two values of A $ ( A_{min},A_{max} )$  so that the graph touches x-axis. To satisfy this,

$$ y = 0, y^{'}=0 $$

Inside this interval of A there are 3 real roots. Outside the interval, it has one real root, two complex roots.

Comment: I understand that but this question was taken from a practice exam. In the actual exam I will not have access to graphing software and whilst I would love to be able to accurately draw cubics from memory, I don't think that's something I should rely on